# Extra Whitespace at Bottom of Scrollview Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I am making an app for the first time in Swift and on my login page the scroll view is adding extra whitespace at the bottom of the screen. If I make my image larger the page lengthens and the whitespace goes away. Can someone explain what is going on and how to fix it/get the view to fill in to the size of the screen? [image: Extra Whitespace] [image: No Whitespace After Image is Resized]

```
var body: some View { 
ScrollView {
if login.isLoggedIn {
MainView()
} else {
VStack() {

}

.background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color{blue), CColor(blue)]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
}
}
```

I might not have the background and the brackets correct in the example, but as you can see it is working in my app.

Comment: You probably want the `Login` button outside the scrollview, so it doesn't scroll with the content

Comment: @aheze I don;t understand how that would help? My login screen is too long to display all the way on one screen. It scrolls down to show all the login buttons.

Comment: Oh I thought you just wanted 1 login button to stick at the bottom of the screen. So you want the background to be blue, and no white gap at the bottom? Make the `UIScrollView`'s background blue, and make the scrollable content view's background clear.

Comment: @aheze What is the syntax for that? I'm having trouble finding it. Also, I was using the ScrollView from the SwiftUi framework.

Comment: Ahhh... I thought this was UIKit.

Comment: Can you show what code you have so far?

Comment: I can give the bare bones. The entire code is fairly long.

Comment: @aheze I added the code.

Comment: @aheze Would this be easier to solve in UIKit?

Comment: It's fine in SwiftUI. I just saw your [newer question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67358313/14351818) which is really asking the same thing, but more focused. Let's move this conversation over to that.